# Existem métricas de classificação para a elaboração de consultas em SQL?

Tags: mysql, sql, banco-de-dados

## Dúvida

Tem algum método para classificar em níveis de dificuldade, uma consulta SQL em fácil, médio ou **difícil**? 
Essa pergunta pode ser um pouco subjetiva, mas especular talvez seja uma boa opção.

## Contexto

Estava respondendo algumas questões de SQL no site do [hackerrank](https://www.hackerrank.com/challenges/) e me deparei com uma pergunta "**básica**" sobre **JOIN** considerada "***easy***", porém eu demorei um pouco para fazer e gostaria de compartilhar a experiência.

Eis a questão: Dado uma tabela **CITY** e **COUNTRY**, faça uma consulta que mostre o somatório da população onde o continente é "Asia". [ask english](https://www.hackerrank.com/challenges/asian-population/problem)
[image: inserir a descrição da imagem aqui]

## Minha resolução

> 1. Encontrar as cidades referente ao pais "Asia".
>
>    > `SELECT code FROM country WHERE continent = "Asia";`
> 2. Mapear as cidades filtrados na tabela COUNTRY com a tabela CITY usando **JOIN**.
>
>    > ```
>    > SELECT code, countrycode, population 
>    >   FROM consulta1 JOIN city ON consulta1.code = city.countrycode;
>    > ```
> 3. Somar a população da consulta filtrada
>
>    > `SELECT SUM(population) FROM consulta2;`

Se juntar todas as *sub queries*, usando ALIAS - AS, chegamos na reposta da questão.

#### Resposta

```
SELECT SUM(POPULATION) FROM 
    (SELECT tab1.CODE,CITY.COUNTRYCODE,CITY.POPULATION FROM 
        ( SELECT CODE FROM COUNTRY WHERE CONTINENT = "Asia") AS tab1 
            JOIN CITY ON tab1.CODE = CITY.COUNTRYCODE) AS tab2;
```

Comment: O que exatamente você está querendo saber? Se a forma que você fez é correta? Se há alternativas? O nível de dificuldade depende do seu conhecimento sobre os comandos SQL para obter o resultado desejado.

Comment: Se você fosse classificar a dificuldade dessa questão qual seria? A sua resposta seria baseada em quais argumentos? Imagine que você tivesse que fazer um tipo de classificação dessas pra uma prova

Comment: Foi exatamente o que eu disse no comentário anterior: o nível dependerá do seu conhecimento. Pra ti, como você informou, foi um pouco mais complicada e pode não ser nível básico. Já pra mim, é básico. Tecnicamente pode-se dizer que essa questão é fácil por utilizar os comandos básicos para `agregamento` e `junção` que seriam os comandos `SUM()` e `JOIN`, que nesse caso foi utilizado `subquerys` no lugar de junções.

Comment: Essa seria uma boa candidata a resposta =]

Comment: @JonathasB.C. , eu creio que falar sobre dificuldade de ligar a ênfase de sintaxe seria tópico para o meta

Comment: @JeffersonQuesado se especificar a dificuldade a esse exemplo de SQL demostrado na pergunta fica coerente ao escopo do SOpt ?

Comment: @JonathasB.C. creio que sim, perfeito para o meta, com a tag "suporte". Estava pensando a um tempo a abrir uma pergunta de formatação como "proposta-para-faq", pois não vi nada na FAQ falando especificamente de formatação, e esse "erro", creia, é muito comum e eu passo muito por ele em respostas multo-linguagem

Comment: Conforme o comentário acima, é difícil responder objetivamente esse tipo de questão. Dito isso, o problema pode ser reduzido a uma somatória e um `JOIN` simples, sem `GROUP BY`, `HAVING`, *subqueries*, funções analíticas, `UNION`, `PIVOT`, queries recursivas ou construções mais complicadas. Pessoalmente eu também classificaria o problema como fácil. É perfeitamente natural porém que uma primeira tentativa leve mais tempo; é igualmente natural que você acabe chegando a uma solução mais complicada do que o esperado. Faz parte do processo de aprendizado.

Answer (score 0):

Você tentou:

```
SELECT SUM(CITY.POPULATION) FROM
    CITY INNER JOIN COUNTRY ON (CITY.COUNTRYCODE = COUNTRY.CODE)
        WHERE COUNTRY.CONTINENT = "Asia");
```

Lembre-se de que SQL é uma linguagem declarativa, não pense dessa forma: primeiro faz isso e depois esse outro e por fim esta outra coisa.

Tem um ) a mais no final do comando. Tente:

```
SELECT SUM(CITY.POPULATION) FROM
    CITY INNER JOIN COUNTRY ON (CITY.COUNTRYCODE = COUNTRY.CODE)
        WHERE COUNTRY.CONTINENT = 'Asia';
```

Comment: Tentei sua solução no site da hackerrank e diz que está errada =(, da uma olhada no link que eu deixei na pergunta e avisa aqui se achar uma solução mais simples.